# How to redirect Core dump and stack smash messages

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, core-dump, segmentation-fault

I can redirect stdout and stderr of a program using `./a.out > output.txt 2> error.txt`

But these don't redirect messages like `segmentation faults`.
So I found

```
{ ./a.out < $TEST_DIR'test'$i'.in' > $OUTPUT_DIR/output$i.txt ; } 2> $OUTPUT_DIR/error$i.txt
```

Yet, the core dump and stack smash messages are not getting redirected.
How do redirect them?

Comment: Seems related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398472/117549

Comment: another cheating way to get around it would just be to wrap a layer of shell around it `sh -c ./a.out 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I had already tried `sh -c ...` as well as `bash -c ...`. No luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Segmentation Fault" messages are not printed by the faulting program, but by the shell.

The `*** stack smashing detected ***` & backtrace + memmap messages (at least on my system) are printed by the stack protector handler directly to the the controlling terminal (`_PATH_TTY`/`dev/tty` is opened directly, with no regard to stdout or stderr, then the messages are written there -- see [fortify_fail.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=debug/fortify_fail.c;h=16549d6dbcf5b6e1f808336894c1f4778b88c5bc;hb=1ff1373b3302e9e095dc4fd4d371451c00190780) and [libc_fatal.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c;h=3906af5ee7078b2c2e257ececc1d94c9749689d6;hb=1ff1373b3302e9e095dc4fd4d371451c00190780) in glibc).

If you want to catch the whole thing, run your your program with script(1) (eg `script -c './rpneval ...'`) or something similar.

Comment: I tried `script`. But did not help. Here is the command I used: `script -q -c '{ ./a.out < '$INPUT' > '$OUTPUT' ; } 2> '$OUTPUT`

Comment: run it like this: `script -c './a.out < IN > OUT' ERR >/dev/null`, replacing IN, OUT,  ERR with the files where/from you want those things redirected.

Comment: What is `ERR >/dev/null` here? It is not making sense to me.

Comment: ERR is the name of the output file of script(1) (**please** read the manpage). You can omit it and have the output in the file named `typescript`. As to the `>/dev/null` you can omit it if you want the output **both** in the output file and in the terminal. And do **not** use the `-q` switch to script -- it prevents any output whatsoever.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Nice. Thank you. I think you should update your answer with the content of this comment. I have seen many similar questions without proper answers. This is helpful.